# Import "sqlalchemy.orm" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

after installed the sqlalchemy using this commnad:

```
➜  chat-server git:(main) ✗ pip3 install SQLAlchemy
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from SQLAlchemy) (1.1.2)
```

then import like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
```

the visual studio code shows error:

```
Import "sqlalchemy.orm" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
(module) sqlalchemy
```

I have searched from internet seem no one facing the same issue. what should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I ran `pip install sqlalchemy` in my terminal from my virtual environment and it worked. Hope this helps